# Yii Fake Form Vulnerability

Tags: php, yii

If the user Fake a form and change an input to ROLE, he can change that field in database.
How can I protect Yii Forms over fake inputs?

Model Users.php

```
array('role', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 'protect forms'. You need to move that data away from the client (ie. forms) and on to the server (ie. php) via a session or some other method of storing state.

As long as the user's machine is responsible for setting the data (ie. through a form) then they can change it to whatever they want. If you don't have a way of independently verifying that on the server-side, then don't expect the form to send you something you can trust.

Regarding sessions, see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession

Verbose blurb from the Common Weakness Enumeration project (http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/807.html):

> Store state information and sensitive data on the server side only.
>   Ensure that the system definitively and unambiguously keeps track of
>   its own state and user state and has rules defined for legitimate
>   state transitions. Do not allow any application user to affect state
>   directly in any way other than through legitimate actions leading to
>   state transitions.

Comment: I agree, as a rule of thumb never trust the user input, also in Yii, only define rules for user input, that way they can't be mass assigned.